# How to dynamically eliminate top rows?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

There is a spreadsheet table which I open in Power Query. The first column has category names such as

```
1
Null
Null
Null
2
Null
Null
Null
3
Null
Null
Null
```

In this situation, I could remove the top 8 rows to leave only this remaining:

```
3
Null
Null
Null
```

And succeed in isolating that specific group. However, if a null row is added to 1 or 2, then it will offset the number of rows being removed.

My question: How to remove X amount of rows dynamically so it ends up with

```
3
Null
Null
Null
```

regardless of how many rows are added or remove above?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Table.Skip function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-skip) can do what you're looking for.
Note that you can either specify the number of rows to skip or a *condition* that specifies which rows to skip.

So if you want to skip everything up until the first value of 3 in `Column1` of `Table1`,

```
Table.Skip(Table1, each [Column1] <> 3)
```